# Why do these HTML5 images render (or not!) depending on how fast I refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

1. Use Firefox 10.0.2 to open Framework.html from this project: http://code.google.com/p/unitspeeds-vhh/ (EDIT: I'm now preloading the icons. Use [this revision](http://code.google.com/p/unitspeeds-vhh/source/detail?r=dc009f2a3fc691383466f2292670874dcd7b95e7) if you'd like to try to debug the original problem.)
2. Hit F5 to refresh.
3. Hit F5 a few more times very quickly.

**Expected**: The unit icons (unitIconObj in the code) should always render.
**Actual**: They never render on the first page load. First F5 usually shows all icons. Some very fast repetitions of F5 cause most most -- but not all -- icons to show.

The basic problem I'm trying to solve is icons not rendering properly the first time, and  I assume this means I need to be preloading the images. I've been trying a few different methods to do this, but the behavior is not strictly reproducible, and I think I just don't know enough about refreshes and caching to figure this out myself. The icons themselves are very small image files, so I'm surprised to see that this is an issue at all.

Very sorry for the messy code and question -- I'm a noob! Any advice would be welcome.

Edit: Here's the part where I load the image file and render it:

```
for (var x = 0; x < sortedOutput.length; x++)
    {
        // Draw the unit icon 
        var unitIconObj = new Image();
        if (sortedOutput[x].Filename == "--") // I don't have real icons for a few units
        {
            unitIconObj.src = "Icons/Creep.jpg";    
        } else 
        {
            unitIconObj.src = "Icons/" + sortedOutput[x].Filename + ".jpg";
        }
        speedContext.drawImage(unitIconObj, ChartBuffer+textBlock+2+4*iconSpace, 50+(x*iconSpace), BarHeight, BarHeight);

    }
```

Comment: maybe post your actual icon loading code?

Comment: Ok! The loading/rendering part is listed now.

Comment: ChartBuffer+textBlock+2+4*iconSpace is probably the issue. What is ChartBuffer? a method?

Comment: ChartBuffer, textBlock, etc are all just constants I set earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this so it waits to call drawImage function until the onload event on the image fires. This will ensure that the image is loaded before any of the other magic happens.

```
for (var x = 0; x < sortedOutput.length; x++)
    {
    var unitIconObj= new Image();  
    unitIconObj.onload = function(){  

          speedContext.drawImage(unitIconObj, ChartBuffer+textBlock+2+4*iconSpace, 50+(x*iconSpace), BarHeight, BarHeight);  

    };  
    if (sortedOutput[x].Filename == "--") // I don't have real icons for a few units
        {
            unitIconObj.src = "Icons/Creep.jpg";    
        } else 
        {
            unitIconObj.src = "Icons/" + sortedOutput[x].Filename + ".jpg";
        } 
   }
```

found this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: I really like this idea, but it shows the same behavior as before: No rendering on first load, and sketchy appearance after random fast refreshes.

Comment: what that says to me is the error isn't on the image loading. It's something else. If you're still seeing load delays when nothing happens until the image is loaded into memory, you can cross that off your potential causes and focus on something else, like maybe the canvas rendering.